# Why my UILabels texts become auto capitalized?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uilabel

I created some UILabels in IB. Setup text in interface builder like this

```
Settings
```

when i launch the app the text become

```
SETTINGS
```

the question is why? My Storyboard is not localized. I do not do any additional setup for those UILabels. It's a clear UILabel class without any subclasses or categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was because of Localization of Storyboards i did not realize it when i ask the question. You have to localize your storyboards on each of your supported languages or remove localization from storyboards at all.

So the flow is.

1. You have a label on your ViewController on some storyboard
2. You set some text to this label
3. a. If your storyboard is not localized everything work as expected
4. b. If your storyboard localized but in some localization you do not have appropriate resources it will autocapitalize this string.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe **autocorrection** or **autocapitalization** is enabled.

Try this:

Objective-C:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    textField.autocorrectionType = FALSE; // or use  UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo
    textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;

}
```

Swift:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textfield : UITextField)
{
    textField.autocorrectionType = .No
    textField.autocapitalizationType = .None
    textField.spellCheckingType = .No
}
```

Swift 3:

```
  func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField : UITextField)
{
    textField.autocorrectionType = .no
    textField.autocapitalizationType = .none
    textField.spellCheckingType = .no
}
```

If it still doesn't work check your Mac and phone if autocapitalization is switched ON.

In Mac:

[image: This is where you can change the settings for keyboard in MAC]

In iOS:

Settings>General>Keyboard>Auto-Capitalisation

[image: This is where you can change the settings for keyboard in iphone]

Comment: Thank you for your response but not. Forgot about this question. I will add answer.